# Determining 3d locations from two images using opencv - traingulatePoints units

Tags: opencv, triangulation, stereo-3d

Given a set of corresponding points bet two arbitrary (ie not parallel) images (eg as found by SURF) , I have used the following in an attempt to extract the 3D positions of the points.

```
def triangulate(pts1,pts2):
    cameraMatrix = np.array([[1, 0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])        
    F,m1 = cv2.findFundamentalMat(pts1, pts2) # apparently not necessary

    # using the essential matrix can get you the rotation/translation bet. cameras, although there are two possible rotations: 
    E,m2 = cv2.findEssentialMat(pts1, pts2, cameraMatrix, cv2.RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0)
    Re1, Re2, t_E = cv2.decomposeEssentialMat(E)

    # recoverPose gets you an unambiguous R and t. One of the R's above does agree with the R determined here. RecoverPose can already triangulate, I check by hand below to compare results. 
    K_l = cameraMatrix
    K_r = cameraMatrix
    retval, R, t, mask2, triangulatedPoints = cv2.recoverPose(E,pts_l_norm, pts_r_norm, cameraMatrix,distanceThresh=0.5)

    # given R,t you can  explicitly find 3d locations using projection 
    M_r = np.concatenate((R,t),axis=1)
    M_l = np.concatenate((np.eye(3,3),np.zeros((3,1))),axis=1)
    proj_r = np.dot(cameraMatrix,M_r)
    proj_l = np.dot(cameraMatrix,M_l)
    points_4d_hom = cv2.triangulatePoints(proj_l, proj_r, np.expand_dims(pts1, axis=1), np.expand_dims(pts2, axis=1))
    points_4d = points_4d_hom / np.tile(point_s4d_hom[-1, :], (4, 1))
    points_3d = points_4d[:3, :].T
    return points_3d
```

I have assumed that my intrinsic camera matrices are approximately I in the above. The R,t as determined by two methods (findEssentialMat->decomposeEssentialMat vs recoverPose) agree, and the triangulated points as determined by two methods (recoverPose vs triangulatePoints) also agree. My question concerns the values I see, which for points_3d are generally in the range 0-50 for x,y and 0-0.03 for z.  As far as I know these values should be in pixels; has my choice of camera matrix=I affected the scale?

Comment: Yes, it directly affects the scale. The camera matrix should contain fx and fy which is your focal length expressed in pixel units: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html. You set both values to 1 and thus you are getting "smaller values" in pixels for your 3D points.

Comment: consider moving your comment to an answer; since its the right answer, i'd check it as such

Comment: Ok, I have done so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your choice of the camera matrix directly affects the scale. The camera matrix in OpenCV should contain the values for fx and fy which refer to the camera focal length (principal distance) expressed in pixel units - [see OpenCV Camera model](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).
If you set both values to 1 you will get "smaller values" in pixels for your 3D points. Usually, (clearly depending on the camera) the values for fx, fy are around e.g. 1000.
[Here](https://www.learnopencv.com/approximate-focal-length-for-webcams-and-cell-phone-cameras/) you can find a nice example for estimating the focal length of a webcam using only the resolution and the approximate field of view (FOV).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a calibrated camera.  You can look for camera calibration tutorial in OpenCV, it gives you the code and explains how to calibrate your camera.

Calibration will give you the camera matrix and distortion coefficients you must use to get undistorted SURF keypoints (aka features) you will use with triangulatePoints.

Usually the computed camera translation is a unit vector, so your 3D points will use that displacement as scale unit.  Let say your two images were taken with you camera 1 meter apart, 3D points will be in meters.  3D scale is never in pixels.

Final comments:

1- Triangulating points this way is not so accurate.  Accuracy is achieved with multiview or slam method, none of them are simple.  And always with calibrated cameras.

2- If you don't calibrate your camera, you can approximate you camera matrix (worsen the results but better than nothing) assuming:
- cx and cy are in the middle of the image
- fx = fy = half horizontal resolution (ex. 1920/2 px) assuming your camera has 90 degree aperture.  Otherwise you must draw a isosceles triangle and do some geometry.